# Determine end of copied range when using remove_copy_if with ostream_iterator

Tags: c++, stl, ostream, stl-algorithm

I am trying to use [remove_copy_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_copy_if/) to copy an `iterable` directly to `stdout` through [ostream_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/ostream_iterator/). The `remove_copy_if` guarantees that the `return value` is an `iterator` to the end of the output range. This return value is useful in a way to determine the no of elements copied to the destination, by finding out the distance between the start of the output iterator and the return iterator. This makes sense when using a container but how to use the same functionality to determine the no of elements copied to the destination if its an `ostream_iterator`.

The following example should make more sense to what I might want to achieve

```
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int  main() {
    int rawdata[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
    vector<int> data(20);
    vector<int>::iterator curr = remove_copy_if(rawdata,rawdata + sizeof(rawdata)/sizeof(rawdata[0]),data.begin(),bind2nd(greater<int>(),10));
    wcout<<L"No of data copied = "<<curr - data.begin()<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    int some_value = rand()%20 + 1;
    ostream_iterator<int> curr = remove_copy_if(data.begin(),data.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout),bind2nd(less<int>(),some_value));
    //if (curr - what???? > 0) 
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can. `ostream_iterator` is only an OutputIterator, it doesn't have such a useful concept of distance because it's single-pass. The end iterator certainly doesn't remember how far it is from the start iterator. The site is saying that the return value would be useful if you passed in a BidirectionalIterator for the output, or especially a RandomAccessIterator. `ostream_iterator` is neither.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I agree. I was trying to see if there is any other feasible ways to do it. Something that I cannot think of.

Comment: I think just the obvious (but tiresome) -- write your own output iterator that wraps `ostream_iterator` and keeps count.

Comment: I think it would be simpler to write your own conditional code that keeps track of often it returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the following non-thread safe , not so elegant solution to make this work.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
template<class _Fn1>
class counter
    : public std::unary_function<typename _Fn1::argument_type, bool>
    {   
    public:
    explicit counter(const _Fn1& _Func)
        : _Functor(_Func)   {
        count = countTrue = countFalse = 0;

        }

    bool operator()(const typename _Fn1::argument_type& _Left) const
        {   
        count++;
        if (_Functor(_Left)) {
        countTrue++;
        return true;
        } else {
            countFalse++;
            return false;
        }
        }
    static int count, countTrue,countFalse;
    protected:

    _Fn1 _Functor;  // the functor to apply
    };
template<class _Fn1>
int counter<_Fn1>::count=0,counter<_Fn1>::countTrue=0,counter<_Fn1>::countFalse=0;
int  main() {
    int rawdata[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
    vector<int> data(20);
    vector<int>::iterator curr = remove_copy_if(rawdata,rawdata + sizeof(rawdata)/sizeof(rawdata[0]),data.begin(),bind2nd(greater<int>(),10));
    wcout<<L"No of data copied = "<<curr - data.begin()<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    int some_value = rand()%20 + 1;
    ostream_iterator<int> curr = remove_copy_if(data.begin(),data.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout),counter<binder2nd<less<int>>>(bind2nd(less<int>(),some_value)));
    if (counter<binder2nd<less<int>>>::countFalse) {
    cout<<endl<<"No of data printed = "<<counter<binder2nd<less<int>>>::countFalse<<endl;
    }
    }
    return 0;
    }
```